# Why am I getting a Type mismatch error when the type matches?

Tags: vba

I am getting "Type Mismatch" error when calling a function, even though the type does seem to be matching.

I am trying to call a function with arguments, and I am converting it to the correct type.

```
Sub RenameColumns(SheetName As String, ParamArray arrColumns() As Variant)
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Counter = 8
    For Each element In arrColumns
        If Counter >= 16 Then Exit For
            'Error Type Mismatch occurs in the below line. CsStr(element) = <Type Mismatch >
            Range(GetColumnAddress(CStr(element), SheetName)).Value = arrColumns(Counter) 'Here I am getting error Type Mismatch
            Counter = Counter + 1
    Next element
End Sub


Function GetColumnAddress(ColumnName As String, SheetName As String)
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = Sheets(SheetName)

    strSearch = ColumnName

    Set aCell = sheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        GetColumnAddress = aCell.Address
    Else
        GetColumnAddress = "$A$1"     'Error!
    End If
End Function
```

`GetColumnAddress` function accepts two strings. I am sending two strings from `RenameColumns` subroutine. One is of type Variant, but I am converting it to a string by using `CStr`, and the other is already of string.

The error is coming exactly from `CStr(element)` because when I move my cursor over this, it says `CStr(element) = < Type Mismatch>`. I am so confused.

Comment: What is the data type of `Element`? That is probably not compatible with `CStr` function.

Comment: Also, your `Counter ` variable is hardcoded to start at 8. You should really use `Lbound` and `Ubound` to avoid errors.